# London postcode Regex Validation

Tags: regex, validation

I'm using the following Regex Syntax to validate a UK postcode in RSForm!Pro:

> ^(([gG][iI][rR] {0,}0[aA]{2})|((([a-pr-uwyzA-PR-UWYZ][a-hk-yA-HK-Y]?[0-9][0-9]?)|(([a-pr-uwyzA-PR-UWYZ][0-9][a-hjkstuwA-HJKSTUW])|([a-pr-uwyzA-PR-UWYZ][a-hk-yA-HK-Y][0-9][abehmnprv-yABEHMNPRV-Y]))) {0,}[0-9][abd-hjlnp-uw-zABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2}))$

the validation works fine but i need to allow only Postcodes inside London.

Here are the postcodes allowed:
WC, EC, E1-E20, N1-N22, NW1-NW11, SE1-SE28, SW1-SW20, W1-14, HA0-9, EN1-8

Is there any Regex that validate only London postcodes and if not how can i run a separate validation after this and check the postcode is one of above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should match only your Matchcodes, assuming that they are a standalone string - otherwise you might want to use word boundries `\b` instead of the anchors `^$`. I don't think there are much optimizations possible, just pretty straigthforward matching all possible codes:

```
^(?:[WE]C|(?:E|SW)(?:[1-9]|1[0-9]|[12]0)|N(?:[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-2])|NW(?:[1-9]|1[01])|SE(?:[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8])|W(?:[1-9]|1[0-4])|HA[0-9]|EN[1-8])$
```

Here is a demo with the positive matches and some negative examples:

https://regex101.com/r/cT6fQ5/2

However - after reading a bit more into the topic, this might be a lot deeper than your initial post provides. I found this website with london postcodes http://www.doogal.co.uk/london_postcodes.php and worked on a solution, that restricts the first 3 or 4 digits specific to london and afterwards uses the last part from your initial postcode-regex:

```
(?i)^((?:EC(?:[1234][AMNPRV]|[124]Y)|WC(?:[12][ABEHNR]|1[VX])|(?:E|SW)(?:[0-9]|1[0-9]|[12]0)|N(?:[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-2])|NW(?:[1-9]|1[01])|SE(?:[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8])|W(?:[1-9]|1[0-4])|HA[0-9]|EN[1-8]|E1W) {0,}[0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2})$
```

And again a demo:
https://regex101.com/r/eD1gW3/3

Comment: Fails to match these cases: `E1-E20, N1-N22, NW1-NW11, SE1-SE28, SW1-SW20, W1-14, HA0-9, EN1-8`

Comment: @noob Imho `E1-E20` means `E1`, `E2`, `E3` ... `E20` and so on, as you can see here: http://www.doogal.co.uk/london_postcodes.php

Comment: Oh ! I didn't knew that. I was only adhering to OP's specifications. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: I've tried the second regex and it seems to do the validations, however it doesn't allow postcodes entered in lower case. for example it accept E1 2YQ but not the e1 2yq. the ideal would be to validate the both postcodes entered in uppercase and lowercase and with or without space. Also it doesn't work for E1W 2YQ.

Comment: @Sami if lowercase postcodes are actually considered as valid (which is neither clear from you question, nor from any further information i found), you could run your regex with an case-insensitive modifier (i)

Comment: @Sami I have updatet the second regex, added an inline modifier for case insensitivity and added E1W to the valid codes. Entering the postcode without spaces should already have worked. Please try, if it works.

Comment: Hi Sebastian. we just noticed that regex gives an error for a valid postcode such as "N10 2LJ"

Comment: @Sami Corrected, I wrongly used `1[1-9]` instead of `1[0-9]` in some cases.

Comment: Could you please help me with the code. Which one should I replace with 1[0-9]. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Sami Please check my answer, I had updated it accordingly.