# Regex to detect a London postcode

Tags: php, preg-match

I need to create a regular expression that detects a postcode and assesses if its a London postcode.

```
"
E#
N#
SE#
EC#
NW#
SW#
W#
WC#
"
```

This is the regular expression I've tried to incorporate - [London postcode Regex Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34957049/london-postcode-regex-validation), but the solution didn't work.

```php
if (preg_match("/(?i)^((?:EC(?:[1234][AMNPRV]|[124]Y)|WC(?:[12][ABEHNR]|1[VX])|(?:E|SW)(?:1?[1-9]|[12]0)|N(?:[1-9]|1[1-9]|2[0-2])|NW(?:[1-9]|1[01])|SE(?:[1-9]|1[1-9]|2[0-8])|W(?:[1-9]|1[0-4])|HA[0-9]|EN[1-8]|E1W) {0,}[0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2})$/gm", $postcode)) {
    echo "A London postcode.";
} else {
    echo "NOT London";
}
```

Comment: you'd be better off using a plain "is it a valid postcode" regex FIRST, then do a simple substring match on the first two chars to then check if it's a london code. because there's no point in testing both `E#` and `EC#` - 'ec' is already covered by the `e` check.

Comment: FYI that list does not include outer London postcodes.

Comment: Regex is just not the right tool for this job. A valid london pstcode is not just the first 2 characters. Example: `WC1 2AB` is valid, `WC1A 2BC` is also valid, but `WC1B 2AB` is not valid and neither is `WC1 23C`. And then there's the whole `S20` exists but not `E20`. You probably should just have a set of rules rather than a single monstrous regex.

Comment: -- well this is the thing - should I loop through those 8 London identified postcodes to see if the regex fails on one of them?

Comment: What are your criteria for "London postcode"? There are multiple orthogonal definitions I'm aware of (maintained by local govt, health board, national govt) which *use* a list of postcodes to represent a geographical boundary. But  none of these can be represented in a regular expression.

Comment: Was only given this list - E#
N#
SE#
EC#
NW#
SW#
W#
WC#